# Deleting element from Store after ExpirePolicy

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, store, ignite

**Environment**: I am running Apache Ignite v2.13.0 for the cache and the cache store is persisting to a Mongo DB v3.6.0. I am also utilizing Spring Boot (Java).

**Question**: When I have an expiration policy set, how do I remove the corresponding data from my persistent database?

**What I have attempted:** I have attempted to utilize CacheEntryExpiredListener but my print statement is not getting triggered. Is this the proper way to solve the problem?

Here is a sample bit of code:

```
@Service
public class CacheRemovalListener implements CacheEntryExpiredListener<Long, Metrics> {

    @Override
    public void onExpired(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends Long, ? extends Metrics>> events) throws CacheEntryListenerException {
        for (CacheEntryEvent<? extends Long, ? extends Metrics> event : events) {
            System.out.println("Received a " + event);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Continuous Query](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/continuous-queries) to get notifications about Ignite data changes.

```java
ExecutorService mongoUpdateExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

CacheEntryUpdatedListener<Integer, Integer> lsnr = new CacheEntryUpdatedListener<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdated(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends Integer, ? extends Integer>> evts) {
        for (CacheEntryEvent<?, ?> e : evts) {
            if (e.getEventType() == EventType.EXPIRED) {
                // Use separate executor to avoid blocking Ignite threads
                mongoUpdateExecutor.submit(() -> removeFromMongo(e.getKey()));
            }
        }
    }
};


var qry = new ContinuousQuery<Integer, Integer>()
        .setLocalListener(lsnr)
        .setIncludeExpired(true);

// Start receiving updates.
var cursor = cache.query(qry);

// Stop receiving updates.
cursor.close();
```

Note 1: `EXPIRED` events should be [enabled explicitly](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/AbstractContinuousQuery.html#setIncludeExpired-boolean-) with `ContinuousQuery#setIncludeExpired`.

Note 2: Query listeners should not perform any heavy/blocking operations. Offload that work to a separate thread/executor.

Comment: For clarification, is your suggestion to query against the expired events and delete the elements from Mongo afterwards?

What would the localListener implementation look like?

Comment: @ApachieIgniteNewbie123 honestly, I'm pretty confident you shouldn't be using listeners for that. It was designed for lightweight operations, and a Mongo round trip doesn't sound lightweight at all.

Comment: @VladimirPligin I am storing data for the past day in a cache which gets persisted to Mongo. After the data expires, I would like the same item to be removed from both the cache and Mongo. The reason being is if my system goes offline I would still like to have the most recent data available. What would you suggest be the best solution?

Comment: @ApachieIgniteNewbie123 Updated the answer with more detailed code sample.